# ld.exe cannot find cannot find -lboost_system or -lboost_filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, g++, mingw

Doing this on Windows, using mingw g++ compiler version 8.1.0

I'm trying to write simple tester that uses boost/filesystem.hpp. I believe that  requires me to statically link **libboost_filesystem.lib** and **libboost_system.lib**, as the documentation states that the header files for these also rely on their separately compiled binaries. To create these binaries, I followed this link from the boost documentation: [section 5.1 Simplified Build from Source](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#toolset)

After this process finished, I know that in **C:\boost_1_72_0\stage\lib** has the following .lib files:

`libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_72.lib`

`libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib`

`libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x32-1_72.lib`

`libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib`

Now for the build attempt. I'm working in **Visual Studio Code** which shouldn't matter since I've built inside it using g++ before and other boost header only libraries. Here's the command + output

Output (command is first):
`C:\mingw-w64\mingw32\bin\g++.exe -g C:\Users\pawlos.campbell\source\codepractice/c++/main.cpp -o C:\Users\pawlos.campbell\source\codepractice/c++/main.exe -Lc:/boost_1_72_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_72 -lboost_system-vc142-mt-x64-1_72 -Ic:/boost_1_72_0/`

`C:/mingw-w64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_72`

`C:/mingw-w64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_system-vc142-mt-x64-1_72`

This tells me ld.exe can't see the libraries. I've tried shortening down to **-lboost_filesystem**, no dice.

Am I missing something obvious? Any suggestions are welcome...

Comment: `vc142` suggests VC++. You can't mix VC++ with mingw.

Comment: I thought about that...but was too tired to chase it down yesterday. Any idea how to build boost libraries for mingw?